# Why is the list length 0? Why is data not being added?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to populate a list with data got from firebase but for some reason the list's length is zero.I'm adding records to the weekExpenses list inside the forEach. When i print the data retrieved within the forEach and the length of the list, it exists and the length is right, but when i print the length of the list from outside, its 0.  The data exists in cloud firestore. In the comments i've indicated where everything works fine and where the problem is.  Can someone please help.

```
getThisWeekExpenditure() async{
  List<WeekExpense> weekExpenses = new List<WeekExpense>();

  var day;
  var todayDate;
  int weekDay;

  for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.now().weekday; i++) {
    weekDay = DateTime.now().weekday;
    day = (DateTime.now().day - i).toString();
    todayDate = day +
        "-0" +
        DateTime.now().month.toString() +
        "-" +
        DateTime.now().year.toString();

    int totalExpenditure = 0;

    //get the expenses for each day and sum them
    await reference
        .document(userId)
        .collection(todayDate)
        .document('Expenses')
        .collection('Expenses')
        .snapshots()
        .forEach((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      for (var doc in snapshot.documents) {
        if (doc.data.containsKey('Price')) //this is true
        {
          var price = doc.data['Price'];
          totalExpenditure = totalExpenditure + price;
        } else {
          totalExpenditure = totalExpenditure + 0;
        }
      }

      var weekExpense = WeekExpense(
          weekDay: DateUtils().getWeekDayName(weekDay - i),
          expenditure: totalExpenditure,
          barColor: i % 2 == 0
              ? charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.orange[900])
              : charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.purple));

      //this shows the weekdays
      print("length ${weekExpenses.weekDay}");

      weekExpenses.add(weekExpense);

      //this shows the lengths of 1,2,3,4,5 records. Which is okay
      print("length ${weekExpenses.length}");

      if (i == DateTime.now().weekday) {
        totalExpenditure = 0;
      }
    });
  }
  //But at this point when i check the length its 0.
  print("length ${weekExpenses.length}");

  return weekExpenses;
}
```

How i'm calling it to test

```
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
         DatabaseService(userId: user.uid).getThisWeekExpenditure();
      },
    )
```

The error thrown

```
    ════════ Exception caught by gesture ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
Tried calling: length

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
#1      _StatisticsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:expensetracker/screens/statistics/statistics.dart:179:38)
#2      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:706:14)
#3      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:789:36)
#4      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#6e788
  debugOwner: GestureDetector
  state: ready
  won arena
  finalPosition: Offset(158.3, 519.5)
  finalLocalPosition: Offset(158.3, 25.5)
  button: 1
  sent tap down
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reference.document` is asynchronous. You have to make your function `async` and `await` that call. Right now your `print("length ${weekExpenses.length}");` is getting called before you populate the list.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've done as you say  but it doesn't work. The last print doesn't get executed and the loop runs only once

Comment: Is there an error being thrown? Just so we're on the same page, I meant for you to call `getThisWeekExpenditure` like this: `getThisWeekExpenditure() async {/*...*/}` and add an `await` before `reference.document(userId).collection(todayDate)...`

Comment: Yes. Made the made the function future like this Future<List<WeekExpense>> and the loop runs once. when i do getThisWeekExpenditure() async {/*...*/} without adding Future type it throws an error  Class 'Future<dynamic>' has no instance getter 'length'.

Comment: Yes, making the function async makes whatever return value a `Future<value>`. I'm wondering if you can update your code with what you're currently doing and how you're using `getThisWeekExpenditure` as well as the full error that gets thrown. Also how do you know the for loop is only running once? I'm just curious whether you're stepping through it in the debugger or something else

Comment: I've updated my code. I knew the loop runs once after stepping through it

Comment: Oh! I think I see it. `.snapshots` returns a stream. Interestingly you can `forEach` on a stream but then that keeps going until the stream is done emitting. You want to query it just once though so in you're case you want to call `.getDocuments()` in place of `.snapshots()`